# J/Link with Environment Variables and Command-Line Parameters

Tags: java, command-line, environment

I have inherited a large number of Java files with classes I am trying to call from Mathematica via J/Link. They are legacy and am not at liberty to modify. A few are used on command-line scripts (with static methods, no constructors [hence no JavaNew]). Unfortunately they require the user to launch the JVM at a specific directory.

Loading Java in Mathematica via J/Link with
    `-Duser.dir=theSpecificDirectoryName  -DsomeEnvironmentVariable=someValue`
neither changes the current working directory nor `System.getenv(someEnvironmentVariable)` return "someValue."

Question: How to make the JVM (or J/Link?) use these values ("theSpecificDirectoryName" as its current working directory and "someEnvironmentVariable") in Mathematica?

Thanks.

Comment: Does running `setProperty["user.dir", "theSpecificDirectoryName"]` after loading JLink have no effect? For environment variables I find if I launch Mathematica from the command line it will inherit whatever variables I had set.